# How can i use double variable in mysql insert values?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an online examination system. but i face a one problem. My problem code is down here.

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE sub_id=$subject_id";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$question_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
for($a=1;$a<=$question_count;$a++){
    $ans{$a}=$_POST["ans$a"];
    $subject_id{$a}=$_POST["sub_id$a"];
    $group_id{$a}=$_POST["grup_id$a"];

    if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO answer(sub_id,grup_id,ans)VALUES('$subject_id{$a}','$group_id{$a}','$ans{$a}')")){
        echo "problem of query<br>";
    }

}

?>
```

i want to use $subject_id{$a},$group_id{$a}$ans{$a} in mysql insert value.

please help me to use those variable in insert query

Comment: What is the error or unintended outcome?

Comment: How about using `$ans[$a]`, `$subject_id[$a]` instead of `$ans{$a}`, ... This won't take care of the vulnerability to sql injection. And you should consider to move from the deprecated mysql_* functions to a more modern API like mysqli or PDO with prepared statements and placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revise your methods as VMAI stated as for your question why don't you just store the values into a single variable before passing it into the query like this:

```
$ans{$a}=$_POST["ans$a"];
$subject_id{$a}=$_POST["sub_id$a"];
$group_id{$a}=$_POST["grup_id$a"];

$_ans = $ans{$a};
$_subject_id = $subject_id{$a};
$_group_id = $group_id{$a};

if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO answer(sub_id,grup_id,ans)VALUES('$_subject_id','$_group_id','$_ans')")){
    echo "problem of query<br>";
}
```

Comment: Okay then, glad i could be of help, please accept my answer. :)